# Make a directory/usb drive Read Only in windows c/c++

Tags: c++, windows, readonly, createfile

I am using **`CreateFile`** to make a directory READ ONLY using **`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY`** as dwFlagsAndAttributes.

However this blocks the access to the drive completely. I can't traverse the directory or see any files inside it.

It shows **Access is denied**.

My code :

```
LPWSTR wszPath = L"\\\\.\\F:";      // path to the drive
HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive
hDevice = CreateFile(wszPath,          // drive to open
            (GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE),    
            FILE_SHARE_READ,  // share mode
            NULL,             // default security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING,    
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,       // file attributes
            NULL); 
if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
    {
        wprintf(L" hDevice INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Error %ld.\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        return (FALSE);
    }
      wprintf(L"Successfully opened");
```

**Error message pic** : 
[image: pic]

As I am passing file attributes as **FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY** so it should be ONLY read only,why It can't let access to the files.

Language : c++

platform : windows

Any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Most likely, elevation (run as administrator) is required

Comment: @dewaffled program is running well.However we can't traverse the files for reading. It shows Location F:\ is NOT available, Access is denied as shown in **pic above**

Comment: You're opening a volume device, not a directory. File attributes can only be set on filesystem files and directories -- not devices. The read-only file attribute is simply ignored. What's happening here is that by opening the "//./F:" volume device with only read sharing (i.e. `FILE_SHARE_READ`), without also sharing either write or delete access, you're implicitly making the filesystem lock the volume so that it's only accessible via the file object that you're creating. Nothing else can access the volume.

Comment: For a concrete example, see [`FatOpenVolume`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L2277) in the fastfat filesystem driver.

Comment: @ErykSun Thank you so much for making it clear for me.

Comment: @ErykSun How we can make NTFS volume as READ ONLY so that no one allowed to modify(paste/delete/create files/folders) there. Only they are allowed to read. 
For FAT32 I have used following code : 

`SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES sda = { sizeof(sda), TRUE }; sda.AttributesMask = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY; sda.Attributes = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY; and then DeviceIoControl( hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES, &sda, sizeof(sda), 0, 0, 0); 
`
But It is NOT working with **NTFS**. 

Can you plz tell me how to do for NTFS **without ACL or registry**?